# Core Data Concurrency Debugging - exc_bad_instruction

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, exc-bad-instruction

I want to optimize Core Data and set the **com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1** flag.  Now I get the **exc_bad_instruction** error for predicate. I didn't find enoght informations about it, only that can be the nil value, but I don't know how to fix it. [image]

Comment: If a `CDUser` is an `NSManagedObject` subclass then it means that you are accessing its properties not from it's MOC thread.

Comment: I am experiencing the same error. Did you manage to solve this ?